# Solana Rust Build on WSL Ubuntu 20.04 Causes Blue Screen on Windows 10

Tags: rust, windows-subsystem-for-linux, solana

I am trying to build [this project](https://github.com/solana-labs/example-helloworld) using Rust on WSL. However, after running `npm run build:program-rust` my computer crashed and showed a BSD (I caused the crash twice to make sure this command was the actual cause).

What is the workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rustup/issues/2887) I realized I was on WSL 1 (you can check with `wsl -l -v`)

I tried migrating my Ubuntu 20.04 instance to WSL 2 by running `wsl --set-version <my_distro_name> 2` and it appears to have resolved the Blue Screen issue.